# Why is getlogin() succeeding even if there is no controlling terminal

Tags: c, perl

I wrote a simple C program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  printf( "%s\n", getlogin() );
  return 0;
}
```

... to try some things out.  I've tried making getlogin() fail by making sure there isn't a controlling terminal, but it's still getting the login name and printing it.  The most extreme example to demonstrate this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(env | grep -vP ^PATH\\b | awk -F= \{print \$1\}); do
  unset $i;
done;
(tty; perl -e 'setpgrp; sleep( 1 ); exec( qw( getlogin_test ) );' ) &
```

In the way of explanation: it un-sets all environment variables except PATH, then runs a sub-shell that executes 'tty' then a perl instance; the sub-shell is backgrounded.  Calls setpgrp to make sure it isn't using the process group to find the parent's controlling terminal (I don't believe it does, but I put it in there in case that assumption was wrong).

At this point, I'm at a loss.  It still prints the username.  A simpler example that I've seen from quite a few sources has the same behavior:

```
sh -c 'time perl -e '"'"'$|=1; print getlogin(), chr(10);'"'"' &'
sh -c 'time perl -e '"'"'$|=1; print getlogin(), chr(10);'"'"' & wait'
```

Both of these still print the username, under both Solaris 10 and Redhat 6 with differing versions of perl, bash, sh, and tcsh.

Comment: getlogin() isn't secure and likely is trying whatever it can to figure out a username.

Comment: Your processes still have a controlling terminal, I'm not sure which step you assume will get rid of it.

Comment: @nos I was under the impression that throwing it in the background should get rid of the controlling terminal.

Comment: @Brian Vandenberg no, not at all.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the post, `tty` prints the message `not a tty`

Comment: @nos, what can I do to ensure there isn't a controlling terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing or redirecting STDIN to a file does the trick.

```
$ perl -wE'say getlogin()'
eric

$ perl -wE'open STDIN, "<", "/dev/null" or die $!; say getlogin()'
Use of uninitialized value in say at -e line 1.
```

This is a self-built Perl (default options) on a Debian box.

Comment: hm.  I tried this with perl 5.10.1: `perl -wE 'open( STDIN, "<", "/dev/null" ) or die "$!\n"; my $user = getlogin(); print( "$user\n" );'` ... but it still prints out my username.

Comment: getlogin() in glibc/Linux pokes around in "/proc/self/loginuid" and calls getpwuid_r , it doesn't really care about the controlling terminal unless that fails.

Comment: That certainly explains the result in Redhat, but in Solaris perl isn't making use of glibc.  It's only loading socket, nsl, dl, m, and c.

Comment: I wish I could remember the conclusion I ended up with, but I don't.  The answer given, while it may not have been exactly what I *needed* was still helpful and deserving of recognition.